# Exclude folder from rewrite perform in nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a situation where I have domain.com as well a separate code for m.domain.com. So I m check if the user is from mobile rewrite to m.domain.com else access the regular domain.com but I have one folder domain.com/blog which  shouldn't be redirecting to m.domain.com even if user is from mobile. I have tried all the possibilities of 'nested if' but missing with something. Here is what I have tried. any help is much appreciated

my nginx.conf

```
server {
listen   80;
server_name domain.com;
rewrite ^(.*) http://www.domain.com$1 permanent;
}
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name www.domain.com;
    set $mobile_rewrite do_not_perform;

if ($request_uri !~ "^/blog/\w+$")
{
   set $mobile_rewrite do_not_perform;
}        

if ($http_user_agent ~* "(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile||iemobile|ip(hone|od)||up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino") {
set $mobile_rewrite perform;
}


if ($mobile_rewrite = perform) {
    rewrite ^ http://m.domain.com$request_uri? redirect;
    break;
}


    root     /var/www/public_html/;
    index  index.php;

location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
 }

 location /blog { 
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
 }

/* and there m.domain.com configuration lines also */
```

with this config: When user logs from mobile it is redirecting to m.domain.com but if user is trying to access domain.com/blog from mobile then it is redirecting to m.domain.com/blog but it should redirect to m.domain.com/blog istead it should be at domain.com/blog

Comment: Please edit your question to fully describe the behavior this configuration produces.

Comment: @tim added the behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name www.domain.com;

    location /blog {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
    }

    location / {
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile||iemobile|ip(hone|od)||up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino") {
            rewrite ^ http://m.domain.com$request_uri? redirect;
        }
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    root     /var/www/public_html/;
    index  index.php;
}
```

Here, the `/blog` location is tested first, if it matches, nginx directly serves the blog.

Otherwise nginx uses the `/` location, where we test the mobile user agent and perform the redirect if user agent contains the desired string.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add locations to your config rather than just using one within the server. This might not quite work and could likely be optimized but should point you in the right direction.

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name www.domain.com;

  set $mobile_rewrite do_not_perform;
  if ($request_uri !~ "^/blog/\w+$") {
    set $mobile_rewrite do_not_perform;
  }        

  if ($http_user_agent ~* " android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile||iemobile|ip(hone|od)||up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino") {
    set $mobile_rewrite perform;
  }

  location /blog {
    root     /var/www/public_html/;
    index  index.php;
  }

  location / {
    if ($mobile_rewrite = perform) {
      return 302 http://m.domain.com$request_uri?;
      break;
    }

    root     /var/www/public_html/;
    index  index.php;
  }
```

Comment: locations are already present in config updated the config here with locations.When i try to add if statement for location / it is giving me error saying "nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:178"

Comment: You really need to ask your question more effectively. That's twice you've given more information, which wastes peoples time who are trying to help. Now you're saying there's a problem on a specific line without pointing out which line it is. Your config file is malformed. I suggest you go back and rework your question to fully set out the problem, what you've tried, configuration(s), symptoms, etc.

Comment: sorry if i didn't asked properly,  i don't want to put whole nginx config of 1000 line and make people confused & also thought loactions are not needed so i didn't gave that earlier, i m getting the error when i change this line "location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
 }" to  "location / {
    if ($mobile_rewrite = perform) {
      return 302 http://m.domain.com$request_uri?;
      break;
    }"

Comment: Please don't put configurations in comments, they're not formatting properly and are very difficult to read. Please edit your question, mark it as an edit and describe what you changed, then if you like comment on the question (not this answer) that you've changed it. You don't need to give the Nginx config, just the server config, which is typically quite short. Most people have each server or site in its own file, separate from the Nginx config.

Comment: thanks for your replies but I have already edited question and when I apply the changes that you mentioned in answer it is giving the error. The only change btw question and answer is location / tag, pls excuse me if I missed anything

Comment: I've looked at your updated question. I believe you need to read my answer more fully, make sure you understand it, then try it. If it doesn't work then come back and tell us what happened. We can't spoon feed you we can only point you in the right direction, and right now your configuration approach needs work. Try it my way, it may not work perfectly but it may spark some ideas that do work for you.